# Agile web development with Rails 4 line items not adding correctly in cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been following along with the book Agile Web Development with Rails 4 and I have reached Chapter 10 - Finishing The Cart.

So far everything has been working perfectly until I updated the cart to show the total price for items individually and the entire cart.

Here is a snapshot of what happens:

[image: Current Cart Output]

Obviously the prices should be showing as a total rather than side by side.

Here is my view:

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<h2>Your Cart</h2>
<table>

<% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>

<tr>
<td><%= item.quantity %>&times;</td>
<td><%= item.product.title %></td>
<td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>

<tr class="total_line">
<td colspan="2">Total</td>
<td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
</table>

<%= button_to 'Empty cart', @cart, method: :delete,
data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Here is my line_item model:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :cart

def total_price
product.price * quantity
end
end
```

Here is my cart model:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

def add_product(product_id)
current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
if current_item
current_item.quantity += 1
else
current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
end
current_item
end

def total_price
line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
end
end
```

Here is the styling:

```
.carts {
.item_price, .total_line {
text-align: right;
}

.total_line .total_cell {
font-weight: bold;
border-top: 1px solid #595;
}
}
```

I'm hoping that there is a simple solution to this and any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: It could be a couple things but we don't have enough information to tell for sure. You might have duplicates in your database, or somehow are creating an array of values for the first item. The output in your form looks like how an array could be represented. What is in the database?

Comment: The database is SQLite. The cart was working fine when it just had to list out the individual products and pricing but when I updated it with the above code it started to give the error shown. I have followed the book until now so I wasn't expecting this type of error. I don't think that it's duplicates in the db as I only have two entries at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the total price for the cart is a string concatenation of the total prices for your line items, rather than their numerical sum.

And the total price for your first line item is a string concatenation of "5.99" and "5.99".

It looks like you may be storing prices as strings rather than decimal values.

To illustrate the problem,

```
>> ["4.95", "5.95"].sum
=> "4.955.95"
```

Check your `schema.rb` and ensure you have this entry in it:

```
  create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.decimal  "price",       precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

If instead you have

```
    t.string  "price"
```

you'll have to revise that.

The proper way to do that is with a new migration*. At the command line, issue

```
rails g migration change_data_type_for_price
```

and in the generated migration file add

```
change_column :products, :price, :decimal, precision: 8, scale: 2
```

then run `rake db:migrate` and you should be good to go.

*Alternatively, since this is a small project you could just edit the original migration file, drop the db, and run all your migrations again and re-seed, but this is not the best-practices approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, you just made my day! I had indeed set my to a string rather than a decimal and it was at the very beginning of the project so I never thought to check. Excellent answer...

Comment: Followed your instructions and it now works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

can you try

```
line_items.collect(&:total_price).sum
```

instead of

```
line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - just tried your suggestion and it hasn't changed the output, the numbers are still side by side.

Comment: @TonyStaunton are you familiar with debugger?